# zsh printf quote bug

Tags: shell, zsh, linux

does anyone have any idea why am I getting hit by this bug in zsh since forever?
It's like a string formatting bug of some sorts:

```
~% printf "%s\n" foo

" foo)foo
```

Basically anything that has double quotes gets interpreted in a similar manner:

```
~% perl -e 'printf("%s\n", "foobar")'

", "foobar")')foobar
```

Zsh config isn't elaborate, just some basic things like:

```
setopt appendhistory histignorealldups autocd autopushd
bindkey -e
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/zike/.zshrc'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

any hints why that can happen?  Thanks.

Comment: what does `type -af printf` show you?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
> printf "%s\n" foo
foo
```

What zsh version do you have on what system? I have zsh 4.3.10 on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

ok. thanks for replies, i've finally unslacked and checked the config file again.
this funny behavior is caused by ``preexec'' hook:

```
preexec () { print -Pn "\e]0;%m - %~ ($1)\a" }
```

`$1` is expanded to the user input and zsh gets confused about format specifier
(`%s` that is).  i haven't found a way to properly sanitize the string, but `tr -d %`
does the job.  escaping `%` didn't help.

Comment: ${1//%/_} but you may find this informative: `printf '%s %s\n' ${(%):-'%n %m foo'} '%n %m bar'`  -- note that (%) causes the variable expansion to have prompt escape sequences expanded.  So perhaps: `preexec () { printf '\e]0;%s (%s)\a' ${(%):-'%m - %~'} "$1" }`